# How to grant access to a user for a specific container instead at db level (IAM)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We have shared environment, i.e., maintaining multiple cosmosdb databases and containers in same cosmos account, I would like to know how to grant access to a user to a specific cosmosdb or container using UI.

Answer (score 0):

There is no user interface for managing users and permissions in Cosmos DB. These must be managed using the SDK (or REST API).

For information on how to manage users and permissions see, [Secure Access to Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#users)

Comment: I'm not sure about the above said SDKs, can you please eloborate more how I can use of it ? Do we need to install it and then we can grant at container level access to the user ? It would be great, if you can share if any article to understand it.

Comment: The article itself has examples on how to create users and assign permissions and gain access passing those tokens. Not sure what else I can share. The sample app may be more helpful if you get that stood up.